# Could not resolve host: mirrors.iuscommunity.org

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, epel

I'm not able to install or update the package on my centos machine .

```
check with 
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopbac

[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 3.7 kB  00:00:00
datadog                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 8.5 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-centos7&arch=x86_64&protocol=http error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.iuscommunity.org"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

 yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: ius/x86_64
```

What might be the possible issues?

Comment: The domain does not exist. There is nothing you can do about it (as long as you don't manage the domain).

Comment: You can follow the suggestions you got from yum.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by IUS moving their mirror servers.
https://github.com/iusrepo/infrastructure/issues/14#issuecomment-572276277 solved me this issue, follow steps:

```
yum erase ius-release
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/ius*.repo*
yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```